# dependsOn on staging slot, multiple commas in resource id

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager

For the life of me I can't seem to get the dependsOn section to properly structure a dependency on the staging slot. I'm getting the following error:

```
Unable to evaluate template language function 'resourceId': function requires exactly one multi-segmented argument which must be resource type including resource provider namespace. Current function arguments 'Microsoft.Web/sites/slots,web01/staging'
```

I've tried numerous ways but they all end up with the same error, below one of the options I've tried:

```
"dependsOn": [
    "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/slots', parameters('webappName')), '/staging')]"
],
```

And

```
"dependsOn": [
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/slots', concat(parameters('webappName')), '/staging'))]"
],
```

Does anyone know how I can solve this issue?

Comment: did you get it to work ??

Comment: Nice!! Please vote and mark my response like valid!!Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary to use the concat function, the resourceId itself accepts several parameters to form the name: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource#resourceid

Here and example that how we use this in my work, to create a config for the slot.

```
"apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
"condition": "[equals(parameters('CreateSlot'), 'true')]",
"name": "appsettings",
"type": "config",
"dependsOn": [
     "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('functionAppName'))]",
     "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/slots', variables('functionAppName'), parameters('SlotName'))]"
],
"properties": {                                
      "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=',variables('storageAccountName'),';AccountKey=',listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName')), '2015-05-01-preview').key1)]"
]
```